# Getting value from my sql data base using get method

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting values from mysql data base using get method i am passing survey_id and question_id from the url

like below
http://myserver.com/emrapp/surveyAnswersScreenOne.php?survey_id=1,question_id=1

but it is giving error

my php code is given below for fetching

```
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from survey_Answers where survey_Id='".$survey_id."' AND question_Id='".$question_id"' ");


     $rows = array();

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     $rows[] = $row;
     }

     echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Then we'll need more of your code.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ please consider this as well as providing the error

Comment: Please note that the mysql_xxx functions are deprecated and that the community has started the deprecation process http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799. You should use PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is having error,this:

```
$question_id"' "
```

should be

```
$question_id . "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be separating get variables with & not , in the url.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you should use `&` instead of `,` between url parameters

`http://myserver.com/emrapp/surveyAnswersScreenOne.php?survey_id=1&question_id=1`

```
$survey_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['survey_id']);
$question_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['question_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

GET params are normally separated with `&` not `,`. So your link should look more like this:

http://myserver.com/emrapp/surveyAnswersScreenOne.php?survey_id=1&question_id=1

Also, please note that GET variables are not automatically translated to PHP variables. You need to pull them from `$_GET` array:

`$survey_id = $_GET['survey_id']`

Answer (score 0):

You does not pass value comma separated in url.You have use & in url like

http://myserver.com/emrapp/surveyAnswersScreenOne.php?survey_id=1&question_id=1

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from survey_Answers where survey_Id='".$survey_id."' AND question_Id='".$question_id"'");
```

you forgot the point for concatenating the string after `$question_id` -> this should fix your issue:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from survey_Answers where survey_Id='".$survey_id."' AND question_Id='".$question_id."'");
```

anyway,also consider sanitizing your url-inputs -> http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from survey_Answers where survey_Id='".$survey_id."' AND question_Id='".$question_id."' ");
```

A dot is missing!

Answer (score 0):

URL and QUERY BOTH ARE WRONG

```
http://myserver.com/emrapp/surveyAnswersScreenOne.php?survey_id=1&question_id=1
```

AND

```
$question_id . "' "
```